# How do I prevent users from accessing mysql?

Tags: mariadb, access-control

I installed MariaDB. I started the server as a local server(127.0.0.1:3306). I want to make sure that the www-data user can't access it. I tried to disable the `mysql` command for that user. But anyone can bypass it by forwarding the port to a different machine and accessing the server through that. I also tried to use IP rules but it didn't work either.

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 3306 --match owner --uid-owner 33 -j DROP

ip6tables -I OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 3306 --match owner --uid-owner 33 -j DROP
```

How can I go around this? My final goal is to make sure that the www-data user can't access the MariaDB server by any means.

Comment: You can't. If a port is open, anybody can connect, if the port vis closed, nobody can connect. Set up users and passwords (and maybe also hosts that are allowed to connect) accordingly, so only somebody who knows username and password comes from the correct host can login ...

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use a system for enforcing access control profiles, such as [SELinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) or [AppArmor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor) for Linux, or similar [mandatory access control](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/mac/) in FreeBSD.

SELinux is often used on Redhat-related Linux distros, whereas AppArmor is used most often on distros such as SUSE/OpenSUSE, Debian-derived, Arch.

With SELinux you can e.g. do something like the below to prevent the web server from connecting to databases over the network:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 0
```

(0 is the default value, though. Use 1 to allow connections.)